# Spring Boot 3 application works on embedded Tomcat but not external

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, jackson

I am upgrading our application from Spring Boot 2.7.10 to 3.0.5

I run it from IDE on embedded Tomcat and external Tomcat (version 9 for Spring Boot 2.7.x) as well. Now I use Tomcat 10.1.7 and Jackson 2.14.2

It **still runs on embedded Tomcat, but not on external Tomcat 10**. I get:

```
Failed to bind properties under 'my-configuration.object-mapper.serializer-provider.generator.write-capabilities' to com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.JacksonFeatureSet<com.fasterxml.jackson.core.StreamWriteCapability>:

    Reason: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'my-configuration.object-mapper.serializer-provider.generator.write-capabilities' to com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.JacksonFeatureSet<com.fasterxml.jackson.core.StreamWriteCapability>
```

Using

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-configuration")
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyConfiguration {
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
}
```

I am able to suppress the error by specifying `ignoreInvalidFields`, but to sure whether it is correct solution.

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-configuration", ignoreInvalidFields = true)
```

It is no doubt that I have to refactor our configuration classes but still, I would like to understand what is going on and why is failing since Spring Boot 3 and external Tomcat only.

Stacktrace

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'my-configuration.object-mapper.serializer-provider.generator.write-capabilities' to com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.JacksonFeatureSet<com.fasterxml.jackson.core.StreamWriteCapability>
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.handleBindError(Binder.java:387)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:347)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$4(Binder.java:472)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:98)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:86)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:62)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$5(Binder.java:476)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withIncreasedDepth(Binder.java:590)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withDataObject(Binder.java:576)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindDataObject(Binder.java:474)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:414)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:343)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$4(Binder.java:472)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:98)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:86)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:62)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$5(Binder.java:476)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withIncreasedDepth(Binder.java:590)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withDataObject(Binder.java:576)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindDataObject(Binder.java:474)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:414)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:343)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$4(Binder.java:472)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:98)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:86)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:62)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$5(Binder.java:476)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withIncreasedDepth(Binder.java:590)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withDataObject(Binder.java:576)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindDataObject(Binder.java:474)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:414)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:343)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$4(Binder.java:472)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:98)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:86)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:62)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$5(Binder.java:476)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withIncreasedDepth(Binder.java:590)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withDataObject(Binder.java:576)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindDataObject(Binder.java:474)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:414)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:343)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$4(Binder.java:472)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:98)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:86)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:62)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$5(Binder.java:476)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withIncreasedDepth(Binder.java:590)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withDataObject(Binder.java:576)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindDataObject(Binder.java:474)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:414)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:343)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:332)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:262)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:249)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java:93)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:96)
        ... 121 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get value for property write-capabilities
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder$BeanProperty.lambda$getValue$0(JavaBeanBinder.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.DefaultBindConstructorProvider.getBindConstructor(DefaultBindConstructorProvider.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.ValueObjectBinder$ValueObject.get(ValueObjectBinder.java:190)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.ValueObjectBinder.bind(ValueObjectBinder.java:67)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$5(Binder.java:476)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withIncreasedDepth(Binder.java:590)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withDataObject(Binder.java:576)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindDataObject(Binder.java:474)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:414)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:343)
        ... 176 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator]: Is it an abstract class?
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:215)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:153)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder$Bean.lambda$getSupplier$0(JavaBeanBinder.java:217)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder$BeanSupplier.get(JavaBeanBinder.java:279)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder$BeanProperty.lambda$getValue$0(JavaBeanBinder.java:357)
        ... 185 more
    Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:198)
        ... 189 more
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? Why aren't you just using the `spring.jackson` properties to configure binding?

Comment: Legacy configuration of rest client. Anyway, the main question is, why does the embedded tomcat behave differently from the external?

Comment: Unless you are creating your own `ObjectMapper` this will influence the global one. Why it is different is hard to tell, is it the same version as the embedded one? Please include the full stacktrace instead of a snippet as well.

Comment: Stacktrace added. It is no doubt that I have to refactor our configuration classes but still, I would like to understand what is going on and why is failing since Spring Boot 3 and external Tomcat only.

Comment: Are there any additional libraries part of yur tomcat setup that interfere with the Spring added dependencies?

Comment: It is a fresh new Tomcat. Wondering whether classloading is different. I was about to report that to the Spring team but when I tried a barebone project, I am not able to reproduce it. I have to dig deeper into which dependency causes such a clash.

Comment: Could be a dependency issue, that while building the war a conflicting dependency takes prevalence over another while running on the command line. Could be an OS difference (Windows vs. Linux vs. Mac sometimes have different resolution orders for the class path).

Comment: Finally, I have a minimal project to reproduce. I opened an issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/35091

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/35091#issuecomment-1516051146 the main reason is that **the external Tomcat has the JNDI enabled**.

It affects property binding. JNDI does not allow enumeration of all of the properties that it contains so, instead of finding all the properties and binding them to the targets, Spring instead has to ask all of the targets what properties they have and then try to bind them. This is when `ObjectMapper` causes a problem.